# Download file to SD Card without using Browser Directory Chooser

Tags: html, silverlight, web, applet, download

Is there a way to download a file from a desktop Browser to a specific location on a SD card without requiring the user to pick the directory?

Steps that would occur:

1. Client goes to web page
2. Client clicks DOWNLOAD button
3. File automatically Downloads to a specific location in a SD card if the user has on in their computer.

This can use any technology.

So far it looks like HTML5 and Silverlight cannot do this. HTML5 is sandboxed to specific locations when using the FileSystem API. Silverlight cannot use the methods that are required in the System.IO namespace. I am guessing that Flash cannot access these locations either. I am not sure if Flex would be able to do this.

I did try a Java Applet which works outside of the Browser but doesn't seem to work inside the Browser. I did sign the Applet but it still isn't working and there are no exceptions appearing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do what you are asking with a modern (or even a semi-modern) browser.

You may need to look into building a native application that registers a custom URI scheme with the target OS.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 5 can do it, if Windows is configured to allow elevated trust in-browser. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: As far as I could tell Silverlight 5 doesn't have access to System.IO.DriveInfo which is needed to get all the disk volumes mounted on the computer and is used to determine if it is a removable drive.

Comment: @ToddSchluechtermann If Silverlight is given elevated trust, it can call COM or P/Invoke to do anything a native app would.